# Where should I format date from a database before displaying it - Android

Tags: android-sqlite, android-contentprovider, android-adapter

I store the date in an SQLlite database as a long and want to view it in a ListView. At the moment I have the Database, a content provider, a loadermanager and a custom adapter. At the moment I'm using the custom adapter to format the data. However, there may be other possibilites, so I'm interested what is best practice.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative, assuming that saving it as a long meets the recognised time string formats as per :-

> **Time Strings** A time string can be in any of the following formats (e.g. the very last one):
>
> ```
> YYYY-MM-DD
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> HH:MM
> HH:MM:SS
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
> now
> DDDDDDDDDD
> ```

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

would be to extract the data in the required display format.

For example consider the following :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mydata;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydata (mydatetime INTEGER);
INSERT INTO mydata VALUES(1092941466); -- <<<<<<<<<< 2004-08-19 18:51:06
SELECT *, datetime(mydatetime,'unixepoch'), strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S week %W of Year %Y',mydatetime,'unixepoch') FROM mydata;
```

The result would be :-

[image]

Reading the link above should indicate the flexibility of this approach.